# Android: How to figure out the *original* position of item in Adapter after filter has been applied

Tags: android, listview, adapter

After a filter is applied to an Adapter containing Strings, the "position" variable doesn't refer to the position number it was originally in before the text filter was applied.

Is there a way get the original position of the item *before* the text filter was applied?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might not be the most excellent solution ever but, you could copy your Array and get the positions from that one as original.